# Discord Intents discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to use this -

```
new Discord.Client({ws:{intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES]}});
```

I am experiencing issues. [See the attached image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wFaC.png) Anyone know what wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined the `Intents` it -

```js
new Discord.Client({ws:{intents: [Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES]}})
```